# How to push data into existing element of the array of objects in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, push, arrayobject

I have this array list of objects.

```
var list = [{
  'ID':1,
  'name' : 'Vikas Yadav',
  'mobile':8095638475,
  'sent':false
},
{
'ID':2,
'name' : 'Rajat Shukla',
'mobile':7486903546,
'sent':false

},
{
'ID':3,
'name' : 'Munna Bhaiya',
'mobile':9056284550,
'sent':false
},
{
'ID':4,
'name' : 'Guddu Pandit',
'mobile':7780543209,
'sent':false
},
{
'ID':5,
'name' : 'Srivani Iyer',
'mobile':8880976501,
'sent':false
}];
```

Now I want to push two more datas in specific element of this array  via forLoop as:

```
var timeAndOTPArray = {
  "time" : new Date(),
  "OTP": req.params.ran
}
```

I am retrieving the list data via cookies into one of the route.

Below is the code I am trying to push the element according to the matching condition.

```
var lists = req.cookies.list;

Object.keys(lists).forEach(function(item) {
    if(req.params.ID == lists[item].ID){  //look for match with name
      (lists[item]).push(timeAndOTPArray);
        newAddedList.push(lists[item]);
        console.log(item, lists[item]);
      }
});
```

Perhaps it's not the correct way. Please help!
Wish you a happy and a prosperous Diwali.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findIndex` and append to update the object into list like this:

```js
//List only with ID, easier to read the code
var list = [{'ID':1,},{'ID':2,}]
//your object
var timeAndOTPArray = {
  "time" : new Date(),
  "OTP": "otp"
}
//Index where object with ID == 2 is
var index = list.findIndex(obj => obj.ID == 2);
//Append the 'timeAndOTPArray' properties into the object itself
list[index] = {"time": timeAndOTPArray.time, "OTP":timeAndOTPArray.OTP, ...list[index]}

console.log(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help

```
var lists = req.cookies.list;

Object.keys(lists).forEach(function(item) {
    if(req.params.ID == lists[item].ID){  //look for match with ID
      Object.keys(timeAndOTPArray).forEach(key=>{
        lists[item][key]=timeAndOTPArray[key];
      })
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Good evening) I can advice you the best option is update with map

```
const listItems = [
  {
    ID: 1,
    name: 'Vikas Yadav',
    mobile: 8095638475,
    sent: false,
  },
  {
    ID: 2,
    name: 'Rajat Shukla',
    mobile: 7486903546,
    sent: false,
  },
  {
    ID: 3,
    name: 'Munna Bhaiya',
    mobile: 9056284550,
    sent: false,
  },
  {
    ID: 4,
    name: 'Guddu Pandit',
    mobile: 7780543209,
    sent: false,
  },
  {
    ID: 5,
    name: 'Srivani Iyer',
    mobile: 8880976501,
    sent: false,
  },
];

const paramId = 4;

const result = listItems.map((item) => {
  if (paramId === item.ID) {
    return {
      ...item,
      time: new Date(),
      OTP: 'smth',
    };
  }

  return item;
});

console.log('result', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

for appending, you can do this,

```
 lists[index] = Object.assign(lists[index], timeAndOTPArray);
```

If you are using es6,

```
lists[index] = {...lists[index], timeAndOTPArray};
```

Answer (score -1):

Here `lists` is an array of objects.
so `lists[item]` is an object, so you cant push an object to an object.

In your code `timeAndOTPArray` is an object.

In your `lists` object, initialize an empty array called `timeAndOTPArray`

```
var index = lists.findIndex(function(item){ return item.ID == req.params.ID});
lists[index].timeAndOTPArray.push(timeAndOTPArray);
```

Comment: He wants to append those attributes...that's what he meant by saying push